# Landscape with table adds an extra blank page when setting \topskip

Tags: landscape, blank-page

Consider the following MWE. I have a chapter with a table in landscape mode. Together with the second chapter, this results in three pages. However, when adding `\topskip 0pt` to the `landscape` environment, then a blank page is added after it (in fact two, since the new chapter starts on an odd page).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Table Test}
\begin{landscape}
  \topskip0pt % <<<< Without this line, no blank page.
  \begin{table}[htb!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{3cm} >{\raggedright}p{3cm}}
  \hline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  1 & 2\tabularnewline
  \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{landscape}
\chapter{Potrait again}
Test2
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have removed some stuff. It seems that the problem is the `\topskip0pt` line. If you don't need this line, your problem might be solved.

Comment: Note that it is normal in book classes that a blank page is added if otherwise the next chapter would start on an even page (this was the case in your original example). If you don't want this, use the `oneside` option of the class.

Comment: What's the `\topskip=0pt` supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

This issue has nothing to do with the `lscape` package: indeed, you can reproduce it with the following simple program

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\begin{document}
A\par
\clearpage
% \setlength{\topskip}{0pt} % uncomment this line to see it happen
B\par
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage
C\par
\end{document}
```

(uncomment the commented line to see it happen).

I’ve made some investigations, and the culprit seems to be the `\@doclearpage` macro in LaTeX’s output routine, more precisely the following line of code

```
\setbox\@tempboxa\vsplit\@cclv to\z@ \unvbox\@tempboxa
```

(line 6696 in `latex.ltx`, latest version), which is meant to send back to the main vertical list “any left-over non-boxes (writes, specials, etc.)”, as the comments in `ltoutput.dtx` say.  Unfortunately, if the `\topskip` glue is zero, the `\vbox{}` inserted by a `\clearpage` command *is* split off too, because it *does* fit in zero points, in that case; so, that box is returned to the main vertical list, where it causes the ensuing `\cleardoublepage` command to insert two extra pages.

To be honest, I’ve not checked all the details, but the following program can be used to confirm, more or less, the above analysis:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}

\makeatletter

\def\clearpage{%
  \ifvmode
    \ifnum \@dbltopnum =\m@ne
      \ifdim \pagetotal <\topskip
        \hbox{\special{Comment: A}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
  \newpage
  \write\m@ne{}%
  \vbox{\special{Comment: B}}%
  \penalty -\@Mi
}
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{\special{Comment: C}}\newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{\special{Comment: D}}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}

\makeatother

\showboxbreadth = 1000
\showboxdepth = 10
% \tracingoutput = 1

\begin{document}
A\par
\clearpage
% \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
B\par
\clearpage
\showlists
% \vbox{} % <<< HERE <<<
\cleardoublepage
C\par
\end{document}
```

It redefines the `\clearpage` and the `\cleardoublepage` commands so that they produce boxes that can be unambiguously identified in trace listings (don’t worry if you get some warnings that say “Non-PDF special ignored!”).  Run it first as it is, and look at the trace produced by `\showlists`; then uncomment the line that says

```
% \setlength{\topskip}{0pt}
```

and look again at the transcript: you’ll see that the result is the same as though you had a `\vbox{}` command in your source file at the point indicated by `% <<< HERE <<<`.

Uncomment `\tracingoutput = 1` to get further diagnostic information.