# TikZ package causing extra page with \topskip0pt

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code has two pages (compiled with pfdlatex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
TEST
\end{document}
```

Why is that?
I can not find anyting in the TikZ manual or on this site.

Comment: Note this is reproducible with `pgfcore` rather than `tikz`, but only when PDF is produced (pdfTeX or luaTeX).

Comment: tikz issues a \clearpage.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/550398/2388 (the first hit if I search for topskip)